# Correct translation for the light switch for a website

Tags: meaning, word-choice, meaning-in-context, american-english, translation

I'm looking for the correct translation for a website (http://www.configurator.simonurmet.com/).

[image: The object to translate]

I'd like to refer to the whole object, I don't need the name of each part for now.
The "whole object" to be configured on the website, as my concept would be composed of just these two pieces: the outer frame, and the button covers; not any hardware or cables behind or mechanical parts of any kind (which will be provided standard by default and mounted later).

The clients will access the website to choose the look&feel ie. colours and materials of the frame and the buttons (and set their wall color to take a look at the contrast).

Does the word "Light switch" describe that? Does it refer or include the mechanical parts and hardware that will trigger the light or will it be fine to name what I mean?

In my language the word that it's used is "placca" (italian).
The sentence that I would use would be like this: Configure your {word}.

Which one would you choose from these? Which one is the most correct?

Plate, Cover Plate, Light Switch, Switch Plate or Wall Plate?

I've searched on the net using google and found some images using these terms, but I'm unsure about the correct usage of those.

I need this for a Facebook application that will have more languages and I've set American English as default, so I'd prefer to have the EN_US equivalent rather than EN_GB.

EDIT [using "Light Switch"] Context (this is what I get on facebook when a user configures the object):

> Tommaso is configuring light_switch.title on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso is configuring a light switch on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso is configuring light_switch1.title and light_switch2.title on
>   Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso is configuring light_switch1.title and 5 other light switches
>   on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso is configuring 5 light switches on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and Maryare configuring light_switch.title on Nea
>   Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and 3 others are configuring light_switch.title on Nea
>   Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and 3 others are configuring a light switch on Nea
>   Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and 3 others are configuring5 light switches on Nea
>   Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and 3 others configured a light switch on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and 3 others configured 5 light switches on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and Mary are configuring a light switch on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and Mary are configuring 5 light switches on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and Mary configured a light switch on Nea Configurator.
>
> Tommaso and Mary configured 5 light switches on Nea Configurator.

Comment: Each of those terms might be valid. Could you edit your question to include a picture and indicate exactly which part of a wall-mounted light switch you're asking about?

Comment: I've linked the website for that purpouse, but I'll edit now with an image directly

{DONE}

Comment: As you see on the image and the website, you can configure each piece separately. What I want to refer to is the whole object once it has been configured.

Comment: See "switch plate" images https://www.google.com/search?q=%22switch+plate%22&biw=1024&bih=639&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ei=bkfGVP7HGqLdmAXQ9YGwBw&ved=0CAcQ_AUoAg HTH

Comment: I looked that on google, but I'm trying to name the object composed by both the outer frame and the buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common usage to refer to the switching device and its surrounding plate is *light switch* (at least in the US). Note that switches can be used to control other devices, such as outlets (receptacles) or furnaces, etc. In those cases, it is more properly simply called a *switch*.

The cover or surrounding trim by itself (without the switch) is caller a *cover plate, switch plate* or *switch cover*.

Comment: Thanks! I was using "Cover plate" but I knew it was odd.. What I want to name is the object composed by the "frame plate" and the "buttons covers" (sorry if I am very bad at explaining the concepts).
All the cables and hardware behind are not considered part of the whole thing.

Comment: It would still be called a *switch* or *light switch*. See, for example, [this product](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Lutron-Claro-15-Amp-Single-Pole-Paddle-Switch-White-CA-1PS-WH/203737001). It includes the switching device and the cover plate, sold as a single unit. It is called a *switch*. The reference to poles and paddles merely describe features of the switching device.

Comment: I believe your answer is accurate, would you take a look at the end of the question? I added some phrases for additional context.

Let me know if I'm correct.

Comment: If you are drafting a website for a product line, I would recommend *switches* rather than *light switches*.  These are routinely used for fans, heaters, etc. *Configuring switches* is a reasonable phrase for choosing the type of switch (single pole, three-way, illuminated), the switch color, the face plate, etc.

Answer (score 0):

[Switch plates](http://t.homedepot.com/b/Electrical-Wall-Plates-Jacks/N-5yc1vZbm8m) or *cover plates for light switches* seem to be the most common definitions:

> - Many people overlook the opportunity to add a decorative flair to any room by switching out old light switch covers. This is a simple trick that turns a utilitarian necessity into a chance to easily inject stylish accents into your home. The selection of **switch plates** comes in a variety of designs, materials and colors. Whether your style is modern, traditional or somewhere in between, we have a wall plate that will blend in with your home décor. (This piece of advertising is just to complete the answer with additional information)

Comment: I believe what I'm looking for is just "Light switch", referring to the whole object. Not just the outer frame nor only the buttons, I'm just looking for more feedback to be sure :)

Answer (score 0):

When using the term "cover plate" you might want to substitute "switch plate" . A cover plate might refer to a full cover while switch plate specifically references the plates used to cover a switch box with the appropriate cut out to allow for access to the switch.

Answer (score -1):

That is (in the US) a "3-gang Decora-style switch with brushed stainless cover"  :-)

It could be running ceiling fans or lights or an electrical window shade, so it isn't necessarily a "light switch" though it could very well be.

See [this well known supplier's website](http://www.grainger.com/category/wall-switches/switches/electrical/ecatalog/N-8gz) for examples.

P.S. "rocker switch" is generic and would therefore be better than "light switch". But "rocker switch" is a term a large number of native speakers might not know.  More context from you would help if you want to get the best answer for your needs. "Wall switch" would be widely understood to mean that thing on the wall that turns electrical things on and off.

Comment: so, the "thing" would be called just a plain "switch"? Is this the word that I'm looking for, to refer to the object? Just simple as that? :D

Comment: As long as you have sufficient context, "switch" or "wall switch" would be idiomatic.

Comment: I need the most general term to use on a custom Facebook object type, what I was using before was "Cover plate" but I wasn't sure about that.
The real properties that matter for the object are the frame and the "buttons", what is behind isn't considered part of it (ie. cables, hardware etc.)

Comment: The cover plate refers only to the (here, brushed stainless) trim.

Comment: Not sure why there's a downvote. An explanation would be friendly and helpful.

Comment: I've updated the answer with what the user will do on the website, and what they will then buy exactly. Let me know if I was clear enough or I'll clarify some more :D

(I Didn't downote, must be someone else answering)

Comment: Are you using this switch as a UI metaphor?  If so, "Configure your wall switch" might be odd, because in real life people don't configure these switches; an electrician (or a do-it-yourselfer) wires them up. Presumably, configuring it would mean that the user would associate each rocker switch with something that gets turned on or off.

Comment: Yeah by UI in this context you mean the materials and colors of the frame and button covers right? That's what I'm referring to and needs to be configured using the website

Comment: No, I meant are you going to use the rocker switches of the three-way wall switch as UI widgets? Analogous to RadioButton?

Comment: No each one of those will toggle an on/off state of a different light

Comment: I think I would say "switch panel" for the whole assembly - even if it included a mix of sockets (receptacles), switches and other devices. (British English)